# GCP API key websites restrictions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-places-api

I am trying to restrict my Google Place API key to a set of specific websites, but the response to the call on those websites is always a 403.

I have tried:

```
https://*.domainA.com/*
https://*.domainB.com/*
```

and

```
*.domainA.com/*
*.domainB.com/*
```

However neither seem to work.
It also doesn't seem to work when I only have one of them.
When I completely remove the restrictions on the key, it does work.

My specific case is a NextJS app deployed on Vercel.

Comment: Filing a suppport case would be good for you, since support agents can personally take a look at your project and see what's wrong. https://developers.google.com/maps/support#contact-maps-support

Comment: I asked them and they suggest I call it from the backend and use IP address restriction. I'm going all-around-the-houses with them.
It'll still be the client that need to request the image, and it'll still need the API key and so it'll still need web restrictions.